# Retrieve input value from form in html and use it in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

So, I need to grab an input value from an html form and use it in flask.  Here's an example  of python and html for reference:

python:

```
@app.route("/post_field", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def need_input():

    for key in request.form["post_field"]:    

        if key == "value1":
            #do the thing I want#
```

html:

```
<form action="/post_field" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="this_name" value="value1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Press Me!"/>
</form>
```

I get a 400 error when I click that Press Me input.

Comment: What port is your development server running on?

Comment: @Kyle, localhost:5000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working for me.  I can access the form data via request.form that functions like a dictionary.  You can iterate over the form key, values with request.form.items() (assuming it's python3).

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/post_field", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def need_input():
    for key, value in request.form.items():
        print("key: {0}, value: {1}".format(key, value))

@app.route("/form", methods=["GET"])
def get_form():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

templates/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/post_field" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="this_name" value="value1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Press Me!"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```